# Spacing and Margin settings in MS Word document using Apache POI docx

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I have two paragraphs and i want 100 pt space before each line. Is there a way we can do in `Apache POI`?

Here is the code snippet

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph documentTitle = doc.createParagraph();

documentTitle.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
XWPFRun run = documentTitle.createRun();

run.setText("Paragraph 1");
run.setBold(true);
run.setFontFamily("Calibri");
run.setFontSize(13);
run.setColor("4F81BD");

run.addBreak();

run.setText("Paragraph 2");
run.setBold(true);
run.setFontFamily("Calibri");
run.setFontSize(13);
run.setColor("4F81BD");
```

Here how to add `100 pt` space between two paragraphs? Is there any way we can achieve this? 
`addBreak()` is not keeping any space between two lines.

And how to set margin spacing in docx?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got the answer..

```
    documentTitle.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    // This does the trick
    documentTitle.setSpacingBefore(100);
```

It left me 100pt space between each line of the text

If you want to add custom margins to your document. use this code.

```
    CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
    CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
    pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
    pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(1440L));
    pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
    pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(1440L));
```