# Set word document page margins through java

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I have created a file by using Java where I want to change page margins but I can't

Here is my code:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();    

paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
paragraph.setNumID(BigInteger.ONE);

run.setFontSize(18);

run.setText("Test");

    try{
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C://WordDocument.docx");
        document.write(output);

        output.close();

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What I want to do is something like `document.setMarginLeft( Left_Margin );` and `document.setMarginRight( Right_Margin );`

Thanks in advance

Comment: see the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17852064/1209205 that uses `CTPageMar`

Comment: I have seen that before I post my question and unfortunately the "CTPageMar" cannot be found. Eclipse proposes to create a class with that.
Unless if it is required to add a library, but usually eclipse recommends the requested library.

Comment: Have you made sure you're using the latest version of Apache POI, and you have [all of the appropriate Apache POI jars and their dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) on your classpath?

Answer (score 1):

I think he/she meant for ooxml-schemas library and [rest dependencies](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components).

Comment: I jave included the following jars from the beginning:

poi-scratchpad-3.10-WORD-20140208.jar,   
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-Also This-20140208.jar,    
poi-ooxml-3.10-Also This-20140208.jar,   
xmlbeans-2.3.0 - Also This.jar,   
dom4j-1.6.1 - Also This.jar

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the body of the document and adding a Section, then adding a `CTPageMar`, this object proovide methods for setting margins for the section you just created.

this is actually working for me,

values are large i suppose 10000 is the total width of a page but i'm not sure about it, so find your own desidered values :)

```
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
    CTSectPr sectPr = doc.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
    CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
    pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(1500L));
    pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(1500L));
    pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(2000L));
    pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(1000L));
```

enjoy

Comment: You should add some explanation to you answer.