# Set margins with Apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, margins

Using Apache poi to create a basic word document, I need to change the page margins. [The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787176/spacing-and-margin-settings-in-word-document-using-apache-poi-docx)  seems perfect, but I don't have the CTPageMar class. I'm using 3.10. Anyone had any luck with this with different versions, or different methods?

Comment: What happens if you upgrade to Apache POI 3.11? (The latest stable version)

Comment: I've downloaded (but not installed) several older versions and 3.11. None of the jar files seem to contain a CTPageMar class. The link in my question is to a two year old post, so I wonder if this class has perhaps been depracated

Comment: You'd need to check the `poi-ooxml-schemas` jar. If it isn't there, then [follow this Apache POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)

Comment: @Gagravarr You, Sir, are a star.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Gagravarr for pointing me in the right direction. Seems I didn't have the full ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar.
This code now sets the margins perfectly

```js
 CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
 CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
 pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
 pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(360L));
 pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
 pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(360L));
```

Not sure what the units are, but 720 corresponds to half an inch!

Comment: As the [FAQ mentions](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025), to fix this long term you need to submit a unit test to Apache POI that uses the class, and it'll then get included in the next `poi-ooxml-schemas` jar automatically. Bonus marks if you also expand the Usermodel code to give a friend interface to margins!